# Is it possible to select (multiple) rows of a JTextArea, similar to how this is possible with a JCombobox?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am using this library that this built on top of Java Swing functionality: https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea

I want to be able to select and deselect rows by clicking on them, but I can't seem to find this feature in the API. Does anyone know if it is possible?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I can't seem to correct it in my question, but I meant JTextArea. It does have multiple lines of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported by default in the current API.

Swing components work by associating Actions with events. The current default Action for clicking on a text component is to move the Caret to the point where the mouse was clicked.

If you wanted to add your own customization you would need to add an additional MouseListener to support the highlighting. In your new MouseListener logic these are some of the step you would need to implement:

1. get the mouse point where you clicked
2. convert that point using `convertViewToModel(...)` of the JTextArea to get an offset into the model where you clicked.
3. Using that offset you would need to determine the starting/ending offset of the text for that line. You can use the `Utilities` class for this. It has methods `getRowStart()` and `getRowEnd()`.
4. Then you will need to add your own highlighting. You can use the `Highlighter` class for this. You get the `Highlighter` for the text area by using the `getHighlighter()` method of the text area.

You would need similar logic for deselecting the Highlight.

Then it may or may not work. I'm not sure what complication you will come across.

Comment: Thank for taking the time to explain and confirming it is indeed not in the current API!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use lists instead of texts:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Comment: Does a JList do syntax highlighting?

Comment: No, but cell renderers can be assigned to the items(lines)...